# Typeerror: undefined is not an object (evaluating view.getQuery) after login for componentDidMount in Emulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, undefined

including componentDidMount in my js code it gives error Typeerror: Typeerror:undefined is not an object evaluating view.getQuery. This problems occurs while login my app in Emulator but work fine in physical Device

```
    componentDidMount() {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("user/");
    ref.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
        var userName = snapshot.val()
        var requiredData = [];
        Object.keys(userName).forEach(key => {
            requiredData.push(userName[key]);
        });
        //   console.log(requiredData);
        this.setState({
            name: requiredData
        })
    }),
        this.pushNotifications();
}
```

Comment: what is userName? can you console.log it?

Comment: Actually this code work fine in Physical device but shows error of Typeerror: undefined on Emulator.